# Adding widgets to the Map in Earth Engine Java Api

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-javascript-api

In there a way to add `ui.Chart`, `ui.Textbox`, `ui.Select` and `ui.Button` to the Map in Earth Engine Java Api? I have tried `Map.add(object)`, but it did not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's hard to help you when you don't provide any script, or even say how adding these widgets to the map failed. But `Map.add()` is the way to add things to the map.

```
var dataTable = {
  cols: [{id: 'name', label: 'Airport Code', type: 'string'},
         {id: 'year', label: 'Elevation (m)', type: 'number'}],
  rows: [{c: [{v: 'SFO'}, {v: 4}]},
         {c: [{v: 'JFK'}, {v: 4}]},
         {c: [{v: 'DEN'}, {v: 1655}]},
         {c: [{v: 'LHR'}, {v: 25}]},
         {c: [{v: 'ZRH'}, {v: 432}]}]
}
var chart = ui.Chart(dataTable)
var textbox = ui.Textbox('textbox')
var select = ui.Select()
var button = ui.Button('button')

Map.add(textbox)
Map.add(select)
Map.add(button)
Map.add(chart)
```

https://code.earthengine.google.com/85284ca42d0b9cc59fbf5d6bdc2ea9e3

Comment: it is possible to set position for widget in the Map?